# Geolocator().getCurrentPosition vs StreamSubscription<Position> in flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation, location

I am currently using `Geolocator().getCurrentPosition` to get user current position... but when I am build an app.. I want to calculate the distance between user current location and her/his house (for example)... but since user can move everywhere and stop at some point.. I also want to calculate that new distance... so the route is like this..

```
Home= A
user first location= B
user second location= C (so user move from B to C)
```

I need to know the location from A to B and from A to C
...So what I want to ask is..is it enough to use only `Geolocator().getCurrentPosition` or am I need also use `StreamSubscription<Position>` to listen for user location changes?
here is my code...

```
Geolocator()
          .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
          .then((Position position) {
        setState(() {
          _first = position;
        });
        _distanceCalculation(_first.latitude, _first.longitude);
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });
```

if I need `StreamSubscription<Position>` to listen for user location changes how the way to apply `StreamSubscription<Position>` inside my code

Comment: you need to use `StreamBuilder` and make your calculations inside `Stream.map()` - for more read [this](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#transforming-an-existing-stream) and [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

Comment: do you have sample code for applying StreamSubscription<Position> and GetCurrentPosition ?

Comment: i gave you two links already

Comment: is that not enough if I only use ```Geolocator().getCurrentPosition```? because in my case.. if the distance between user location and Home is less than 500 meters.. they can do my command... if not they should move to another place so that they can do my command

Comment: `Geolocator().getCurrentPosition()` gives you one event if you want to get it as you move you need a stream of events: `getPositionStream()`

Comment: so using ```Geolocator().getCurrentPosition()```, I can get my first location... but wherever I move... using ```Geolocator().getCurrentPosition()```, I can not get my update location... am I right if I say like that?

Comment: `Geolocator().getPositionStream()` gives you a steram of all your locations as you move - more here: https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Geolocator/getPositionStream.html

Comment: so what I need to do is.. change my method from ```Geolocator().getCurrentPosition()``` to ```Geolocator().getPositionStream()```, right ? or... from my code... do I need both of them (```Geolocator().getCurrentPosition()``` and ```Geolocator().getPositionStream()```) ?